# Set vlan_filtering on bridge correctly ["Operation not supported"]

Tags: networking, bridge, vlan

I'm trying to follow the answer on this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546136/bridged-interfaces-and-vlan-tags). Yet, when I try to add a bridge with the "vlan_filtering 1" attribute:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo brctl addbr br0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ip link add name br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

I already ensured that the 8021q module is loaded and that the vlan package is installed. Can anybody see why we are not able to set the vlan_filtering on the bridge?
We also tried to enable it by writing here:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/net/brx/bridge/vlan_filtering
```

But this file does not exist either. The system we use is a Raspberry Pi with the newest Raspbian. So VLAN should be supported. Thanks for any help!

Comment: First correct your two mistakes: don't create the bridge using brctl since you will create it with `ip link add ...`: this would give the error `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` (which is not your error). Then  use `/sys/class/net/br0/ ...` since the bridge is called `br0` not `brx`. But given you got `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported` anyway something else must be going on.You should use my remarks to try again and edit your answer to avoid the 2 additional problems. Also can you add the output of `grep VLAN_FILTERING /boot/config*`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used the .../net/br0/ directory but the file was not there. I will switch to using ip to create the bridge and will post the output of grep later today.

Comment: You never told what was your issue. VLAN_FILTERING feature not compiled in the kernel I guess? Maybe it's time to remove this question if there's no question anymore?